# Replace single quote to double using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I really need to know this, it is possible to address all the textbox in vb.net and replace single quotes to double quotes? because im having problem on inserting data in ms access.. this is my current code:

```
Public Module Functions
    Public Sub singleqoute()
        Dim ctrl As Control
        Dim txt As TextBox

        For Each ctrl In ManageItems.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                txt = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace("'", "''")
            End If
        Next
        For Each ctrl In ManageBorrowers.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                txt = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                txt.Text = Replace(txt.Text, "'", "''")
            End If
        Next
        For Each ctrl In ManageTransactions.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                txt = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                txt.Text = Replace(txt.Text, "'", "''")
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: >`because im having problem on inserting data in ms access`. No no NO NO **NO!** This is so **wrong**. The fix for inserting quotes into a DB this is _**not**_ to double them! That will still leave you potentially open to sql injection attacks! The fix is to use parameterized queries!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn.  Woah nelly.  Your content is right, but your tone is wrong.  As it stands, your comment doesn't offer anything constructive to the asker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use ControlChars.Quote in this case. Also, consider using the .Replace method on string rather than the replace operator with VB.Net:

```
txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace("'", ControlChars.Quote)
```

That being said, I suspect the reason you are trying to do the replacement is to avoid malformed SQL statements that you are creating by using string concatenation. This is a potential security issue called [SQL Injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). It's better to use [parameterized queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927192856/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.2.shtml) and avoid the concatenation issues.

Comment: ControlChars.Quote would return a single double quote, not double the single quotes as needed for SQL strings with single quotes in them.

Comment: True from reading his code rather than the question. You could do that with `.Replace("'", "''")`. My point about Sql Injection and parameterized queries still stands and removes the need to do the string replacement in the first place.

Comment: Agreed, but I think he just misspoke in the OP. We use dynamic SQL extensively in a closed environment so we don't worry about injection issues. Even if we experienced one there isn't anything to "steal." I agree totally that SQL injection is a problem and best practice would be to defend against it. I would think one could defend against SQL injection short of parameterized queries - perhaps just looking for a singleton double quote where there should only be text or a double double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **`'`**, you can write `chr(39)`.

39 is the ASCII value of `'`